# SQL - Finding Customer's largest Location by Order $

Tags: sql

I have a table with customer IDs, location IDs, and their order values. I need to select the location ID for each customer with the largest spend

```
Customer   |  Location   |  Order $
1          |  1A         | 100
1          |  1A         | 20
1          |  1B         | 100
2          |  2A         | 50
2          |  2B         | 20
2          |  2B         | 50
```

So I would get

```
Customer   |  Location   |  Order $
1          |  1A         | 120
2          |  2B         | 70
```

I tried something like this:

```
SELECT
   a.CUST
  ,a.LOC
  ,c.BOOKINGS
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT TOP 1 b.CUST, b.LOC, sum(b.ORDER_VAL) as BOOKINGS
   FROM ORDER_TABLE b
   GROUP BY b.CUST, b.LOC
   ORDER BY BOOKINGS DESC) as c
INNER JOIN ORDER_TABLE a
   ON a.CUST =  c.CUST
```

But that just returns the top order.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: Why you remove the `MySQL` tag? How you want to handle the ties between location from same customer, is that an isssue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use variables to emulate `ROW_NUM()`

**[DEMO](http://rextester.com/GEF78876)**

```
SELECT *
FROM ( SELECT `Customer`, `Location`, SUM(`Order`) as `Order`, 
               @rn := IF(@customer = `Customer`,
                         @rn + 1,
                         IF(@customer := `Customer`, 1, 1)
                        ) as rn
        FROM Table1
        CROSS JOIN (SELECT @rn := 0, @customer := '') as par
        GROUP BY `Customer`, `Location`
        ORDER BY `Customer`,  SUM(`Order`)  DESC
      ) t
WHERE t.rn = 1
```

Comment: That did it. Numbered the rows by Customer and used all the ones with ROW=1. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Firs you have to sum the values for each location:

```
select Customer, Location, Sum(Order) as tot_order
from order_table
group by Customer, Location
```

then you can get the maximum order with MAX, and the top location with a combination of group_concat that will return all locations, ordered by total desc, and substring_index in order to get only the top one:

```
select
  Customer,
  substring_index(
    group_concat(Location order by tot_order desc),
    ',', 1
  ) as location,
  Max(tot_order) as max_order
from (
  select Customer, Location, Sum(Order) as tot_order
  from order_table
  group by Customer, Location
) s
group by Customer
```

(if there's a tie, two locations with the same top order, this query will return just one)

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
select a.* 
from (
    select customer, location, SUM(val) as s 
    from orders 
    group by customer, location
    ) as a 
left join  
    (
    select customer, MAX(b.tot) as t 
    from ( 
        select customer, location, SUM(val) as tot 
        from orders 
        group by customer, location
        ) as b 
        group by customer
    ) as c 
on a.customer = c.customer where a.s = c.t;
```

Comment: That would just return the order value for each location, but not give me the most valuable location.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I'd handle it (maybe not the best method?) - I wrote it using a CTE first, only to see that MySQL doesn't support CTEs, then switched to writing the same subquery twice:

```
SELECT B.Customer, C.Location, B.MaxOrderTotal
FROM
(
    SELECT A.Customer, MAX(A.OrderTotal) AS MaxOrderTotal
    FROM
    (
        SELECT Customer, Location, SUM(`Order`) AS OrderTotal
        FROM Table1
        GROUP BY Customer, Location
    ) AS A
    GROUP BY A.Customer
) AS B INNER JOIN 
(
    SELECT Customer, Location, SUM(`Order`) AS OrderTotal
    FROM Table1
    GROUP BY Customer, Location
) AS C ON B.Customer = C.Customer AND B.MaxOrderTotal = C.OrderTotal;
```

Edit:  used the table structure provided

This solution will provide multiple rows in the event of a tie.
[SQL fiddle for this solution](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/af9a8d/1/0)

Answer (score 0):

This seems like an order by using aggregate function problem.  Here is my stab at it;

```
SELECT 

  c.customer, 
  c.location, 

  SUM(`order`) as `order_total`,
  (
  SELECT 

    SUM(`order`) as `order_total`

    FROM customer cm


    WHERE cm.customer = c.customer
    GROUP BY location
    ORDER BY `order_total` DESC LIMIT 1

  ) as max_order_amount


FROM customer c   
GROUP BY location
HAVING max_order_amount = order_total
```

Here is the SQL fiddle.  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2ac0d1/1

Answer (score 0):

```
with 
Q_1 as
(
select customer,location, sum(order_$) as order_sum
from cust_order
group by customer,location
order by customer, order_sum desc
),

Q_2 as
(
  select customer,max(order_sum) as order_max
  from Q_1
  group by customer
),

Q_3 as
(
  select Q_1.customer,Q_1.location,Q_1.order_sum
  from Q_1 inner join Q_2 on Q_1.customer = Q_2.customer and Q_1.order_sum = Q_2.order_max
)

select * from Q_3
```

Q_1 - selects normal aggregate, Q_2 - selects max(aggregate) out of Q_1 and Q_3 selects customer,location, sum(order) from Q_1 which matches with Q_2

Comment: Some explanations about this code only answer would be useful.